# Flink Table API & SQL and map types (Scala)

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I am using Flink's Table API and/or Flink's SQL support (Flink 1.3.1, Scala 2.11) in a **streaming** environment. I'm starting with a `DataStream[Person]`, and `Person` is a case class that looks like:

```
Person(name: String, age: Int, attributes: Map[String, String])
```

All is working as expected until I start to bring `attributes` into the picture.

For example:

```
val result = streamTableEnvironment.sql(
"""
|SELECT
|name,
|attributes['foo'],
|TUMBLE_START(rowtime, INTERVAL '1' MINUTE)
|FROM myTable
|GROUP BY TUMBLE(rowtime, INTERVAL '1' MINUTE), name, attributes['foo']
|""".stripMargin)
```

... leads to:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: Type is not supported: ANY
>       at org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException$.apply(exceptions.scala:53)
>       at org.apache.flink.table.calcite.FlinkTypeFactory$.toTypeInfo(FlinkTypeFactory.scala:341)
>       at org.apache.flink.table.plan.logical.LogicalRelNode$$anonfun$12.apply(operators.scala:531)
>       at org.apache.flink.table.plan.logical.LogicalRelNode$$anonfun$12.apply(operators.scala:530)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>       at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
>       at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
>       at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
>       at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>       at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
>       at org.apache.flink.table.plan.logical.LogicalRelNode.(operators.scala:530)
>       at org.apache.flink.table.api.TableEnvironment.sql(TableEnvironment.scala:503)
>       at com.nordstrom.mdt.Job$.main(Job.scala:112)
>       at com.nordstrom.mdt.Job.main(Job.scala)

Note: this error occurs whether or not the specific map key is present. Also note that if I do *not* specify a map key at all, I get a different error which makes sense; that scenario is not at play here.

This PR *seems* to say that there's a path forward: https://github.com/apache/flink/pull/3767. Looking specifically at the [test case](https://github.com/apache/flink/pull/3767/files#diff-02b89629e5712a3ea2b9fe195a41760d), it suggests that type information is possible with DataSets. None of the relevant methods `fromDataStream` and `registerDataStream` offer a way to provide type information.

*Is* this possible? In other words, can Flink SQL on Streams support maps?

Clarifying edit...
*When* omitting the map key (`GROUP BY ... attributes` rather than `attributes['foo']`), I get the error below. This indicates that the runtime does know that these are strings.

> This type (interface scala.collection.immutable.Map[scala.Tuple2(_1: String, _2: String)]) cannot be used as key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, Flink SQL supports only Java `java.util.Map`. Scala maps are treated as a blackbox with Flink `GenericTypeInfo`/SQL `ANY` data type. Therefore, you can forward these blackboxes and use them within scalar functions but accessing with the `['key']` operator is not supported.

So either you use a Java map or you implement the access operation yourself in a UDF.

I created an issue for your problem: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-7360

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thank you.

For anyone reading along, https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/table/udfs.html#scalar-functions goes into detail about how to do this.

Comment: Does  the ['key'] work with java.util.map?  I'm using Map<String,String> event;   select event['abc'] from  orderevent. And I still see the exception with error Type is not supported: ANY. I'm using flink 1.3.1. Am i missing anything ? Can you point me to an example where it works? Thanks.

Comment: @thisisananth Can you show some example to reproduce? If it is a bug, I will try to fix it.

Comment: @twalthr Please see the question I've added for the example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45621542/flink-sql-api-with-map-types