# Does Flink SQL support Java Map types?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I'm trying to access a key from a map using Flink's SQL API. It fails with the error  Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: Type is not supported: ANY
Please advise how i can fix it. 
Here is my event class

```java
     public class EventHolder {

        private Map<String,String> event;

        public Map<String, String> getEvent() {
            return event;
        }

        public void setEvent(Map<String, String> event) {
            this.event = event;
        }
    }
```

Here is the main class which submits the flink job

```java
public class MapTableSource {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        DataStream<EventHolder> mapEventStream = env.fromCollection(getMaps());

        // register a table and use SQL
        StreamTableEnvironment tableEnv = TableEnvironment.getTableEnvironment(env);
        tableEnv.registerDataStream("mapEvent", mapEventStream); 
        //tableEnv.registerFunction("orderSizeType", new OrderSizeType());

        Table alerts = tableEnv.sql(
                "select event['key'] from mapEvent ");

        DataStream<String> alertStream = tableEnv.toAppendStream(alerts, String.class);

        alertStream.filter(new FilterFunction<String>() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = -2438621539037257735L;

            @Override
            public boolean filter(String value) throws Exception {
                System.out.println("Key value is:"+value);
                return value!=null;
            }
        });

        env.execute("map-tablsource-job");
    }

    private static List<EventHolder> getMaps(){
        List<EventHolder> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            EventHolder holder = new EventHolder();
            Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("key", "value");
            holder.setEvent(map);
            list.add(holder);
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

When I run it I'm getting the exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: Type is not supported: ANY
at org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException$.apply(exceptions.scala:53)
at org.apache.flink.table.calcite.FlinkTypeFactory$.toTypeInfo(FlinkTypeFactory.scala:341)
at org.apache.flink.table.plan.logical.LogicalRelNode$$anonfun$12.apply(operators.scala:530)
at org.apache.flink.table.plan.logical.LogicalRelNode$$anonfun$12.apply(operators.scala:529)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:742)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1194)
at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:245)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
at org.apache.flink.table.plan.logical.LogicalRelNode.<init>(operators.scala:529)
at org.apache.flink.table.api.TableEnvironment.sql(TableEnvironment.scala:503)
at com.c.p.flink.MapTableSource.main(MapTableSource.java:25)
```

I'm using flink 1.3.1

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem lies in `fromCollection`. Flink is not able to extract the needed type information because of Java limitations (i.e. type erasure). Therefore you map is treated as black box with SQL ANY type. You can verify the types of your table by using `tableEnv.scan("mapEvent").printSchema()`. You can specify the type information in `fromCollection` with `Types.MAP(Types.STRING, Types.STRING)`.

Comment: Thanks for the update. In the real program, I'm not using the fromCollection. This is just in the example program. In reality I'm using the FlinkKinesisConsumer to get the events. In the deserializer, I'm doing this                                                                                                          Map<String, String> map = gson.fromJson(new String(message), new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>(){}.getType());
   EventHolder eventHolder = new EventHolder();
   eventHolder.setEvent(map);
   return eventHolder;

Comment: I'm registering the eventstream like this. DataStream<Row> orderEventStream = env.addSource(new FlinkKinesisConsumer<>(
      params.get("events.stream"), new EventDeserializationSchema(), consumerConfig)); Even with this, I'm getting the same error. So I think the issue is not just with the fromCollection

Comment: If you print `new TypeHint<Map<String, String>>(){}.getType()` you will see that even this is GenericTypeInfo. I agree that this is confusing, but maps where not supported initially. I don't know if we can change this behavior because of backwards compatibility.

Comment: I opened an issue for this problem: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-7425

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar issue with the following:

```
//Should probably make MapVal more generic, but works for this example
public class MapVal extends ScalarFunction {
    public String eval(Map<String, String> obj, String key) {
        return obj.get(key);
    }
}

public class Car {
    private String make;
    private String model;
    private int year;
    private Map<String, String> attributes;
    //getters/setters...
}

//After registering Stream and TableEnv etc

tableEnv.registerFunction("mapval", new MapVal());

Table cars = tableEnv
                .scan("Cars")
                .select("make, model, year, attributes.mapval('name')");
```