# FLINK ,trigger event based on JSON dynamic input data ( like map object data)

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep, flink-sql, flink-batch

I would like to know if FLINK can support my requirement, I have gone through with lot of articles but not sure if my case can be solved or not

Case:
I have two input source. a)Event b)ControlSet
Event sample data is:

```
event 1-
{
   "id" :100
   "data" : {
             "name" : "abc"
            }
}

event 2-
{
   "id" :500
   "data" : {
             "date" : "2020-07-10";
             "name" : "event2"
            }
}
```

if you see event-1 and event-2 both have different attribute in "data". so consider like data is free  form field and name of the attribute can be same/different.

ControlSet will give us instruction to execute the trigger. for example trigger condition could be like

```
(id = 100 && name = abc) OR (id =500 && date ="2020-07-10")
```

please help me if these kind of scenario possible to run in flink and what could be the best way. I dont think patternCEP or SQL can help here and not sure if event dataStream can be as JSON object and  can be query like JSON path on this.

Comment: Are these trigger conditions supplied at compile time, or while the application is running?

Comment: Is there any fixed pattern to how the ids are used in the queries? Do you need to scale this out so that it runs in parallel?

Comment: Thanks David for quick reply, yes these conditions will come at run time and if parallelism cab be supported then great!! But challenge is unpredictable events data attribute in "data" (it is like Map<String, String> data) .

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be done with Flink. And CEP and SQL don't help, since they require that the pattern is known at compile time.

For the event stream, I propose to key this stream by the id, and to store the attribute/value data in keyed `MapState`, which is a kind of keyed state that Flink knows how to manage, checkpoint, restore, and rescale as necessary. This gives us a distributed map, mapping ids to hash maps holding the data for each id.

For the control stream, let me first describe a solution for a simplified version where the control queries are of the form

```
(id == key) && (attr == value)
```

We can simply key this stream by the id in the query (i.e., *key*), and connect this stream to the event stream. We'll use a `RichCoProcessFunction` to hold the MapState described above, and as these queries arrive, we can look to see what data we have for *key*, and check if `map[attr] == value`.

To handle more complex queries, like the one in the question

```
(id1 == key1 && attr1 == value1) OR (id2 == key2 && attr2 == value2)
```

we can do something more complex.

Here we will need to assign a unique id to each control query.

One approach would be to broadcast these queries to a `KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction` that once again is holding the MapState described above. In the `processBroadcastElement` method, each instance can use `applyToKeyedState` to check on the validity of the components of the query for which that instance is storing the keyed state (the attr/value pairs derived from the data field in the even stream). For each keyed component of the query where an instance can supply the requested info, it emits a result downstream.

Then after the `KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction` we key the stream by the control query id, and use a `KeyedProcessFunction` to assemble together all of the responses from the various instances of the `KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction`, and to determine the final result of the control/query message.

It's not really necessary to use broadcast here, but I found this scheme a little more straightforward to explain. But you could instead route keyed copies of the query to only the instances of the `RichCoProcessFunction` holding MapState for the keys used in the control query, and then do the same sort of assembly of the final result afterwards.

That may have been hard to follow. What I've proposed involves composing two techniques I've coded up before in examples: https://github.com/alpinegizmo/flink-training-exercises/blob/master/src/main/java/com/ververica/flinktraining/solutions/datastream_java/broadcast/TaxiQuerySolution.java is an example that uses broadcast to trigger the evaluation of query predicates across keyed state, and https://gist.github.com/alpinegizmo/5d5f24397a6db7d8fabc1b12a15eeca6 is an example that uses a unique id to re-assemble a single response after doing multiple enrichments in parallel.

Comment: sorry my previous comment is deleted by mistake :( .. I tried to implement same way as mentioned by you or as per your repo but if event or control any one of them is slow steam then it start throwing NPE as it goes to check condition for every new control or event. In my case when FLink will start it will get all the control set once and event will keep coming. control set may come during the day but frequency will be very less. am I missing anything ?

Comment: Also, will scalar function help on this?

Comment: For control messages that come before the events, you can store the messages from the control stream in either keyed or broadcast state (depending on how they are communicated), and then use them as new events arrive.

Comment: Don't understand your question about scalar functions.

Comment: well, was going through this article and using ScalarFuntion we can define our own function and register it with table env. then it will help to query data on MAP data type.https://www.bookstack.cn/read/apache-flink-1.9/eefcd88fcdbe8ecb.md#Scalar%20Functions   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45621542/does-flink-sql-support-java-map-types

Comment: Yes, I can see how you might be able to implement your app as some sort of SQL/table join on the two streams.